Connection Between Derivations of Finite and Infinite Binomial Expansion
At first when learning the binomial expansion you learn it in the case of working as a shortcut to multiplying out brackets - anti-factorising if you will. In these cases what you are expanding takes up the form $(a+b)^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer e.g. $(x+y)^4$.
When $n$ is small you could "FOIL" but the generic expansion is:
$$(a+b)^n=a^n+na^{n-1}b+{n\choose 2}a^{n-2}b^2+\ldots+b^n$$
where there are a bunch of ${n}\choose{r}$ coefficients:
$${n\choose r}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-r+1)}{r!}$$
which in the case of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be rewritten entirely in terms of factorials. The argument accompanying this is a combinatorics one, where the original binomial is written as a bunch of adjacent binomials:
$$(a+b)(a+b)(a+b)(a+b)(a+b) \ldots $$
and then for the $a^r$ term you are finding how many ways you can multiply $r$ many $a$s from a set of $n$ of them. (The formula for the choose functions themselves is not the point of this question but I'm sure can be found elsewhere).
This argument only works for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ because it makes no sense to discuss say $\frac{1}{2}$ or $-1$ brackets in a line. Also note that there needed to be no talk of any functions of anything here. This is just a general algebraic technique.
When "expanding" takes on the more general meaning of writing functions in terms of some power series, rather than just the inverse of factorising, you are introduced to the infinite binomial expansion.
$$ (1+x)^n = 1+nx+{n\choose 2}x^2+{n\choose 3}x^3+\ldots$$
where ${n\choose r}$ is defined as above.
This is just the Taylor Series of $(1+x)^n$ (centred at $0$) (all binomials can be made to look like this form with enough pre-processing) and holds for all $n$ (which includes things we don't typically use index notation to write like $\frac{1}{1+x}$ or $\sqrt{1+x}$) when $|x|<1$ (and also some edge cases). Notably it holds for all $x$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ - in other words the two results agree where they are both defined (because at some point the coefficients all become $0$ so the series terminates). Now on the one hand this is reassuring. It wouldn't make sense if there were two unique power series for the same function.
The problem is these derivations have nothing to do with each other. The general coefficient for the term of $k$th degree in a Taylor Series (centred at $0$) looks like:
$$\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$$
The $n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots$ part comes from the $f^{(k)}(0)$ part where the power rule causes the $n$ in $(1+x)^n$ to keep coming down to the front, then having $1$ knocked off of it, then repeating. The $r!$ is self-explanatory.
The same results coming from two seemingly disconnected derivations makes me believe there should be some underlying connection between choose functions and either the power rule for differentiation or Taylor's theorem. But I can't think of any use of combinatorics in derivations for the power rule. And admittedly as an undergraduate physics student I don't have a great knowledge of analysis which is behind deriving Taylor's theorem but nothing comes to mind.
I've learnt in maths there are few coincidences without underlying connections. Can someone help me see if there is an intuitive link between the arguments?

The connection is that there is a combinatorial interpretation of differentiation in terms of generating functions.
It goes like this: suppose $A(x) = \sum a_k x^k$ is a generating function where $a_k$ counts the number of ways to perform some sort of combinatorial construction (it's surprisingly difficult to be precise about what this means but we only need a very special case) to a collection of $k$ ordered objects, then its derivative
$$\frac{d}{dx} A(x) = \sum ka_k x^{k-1} = \sum (k+1) a_{k+1} x^k$$
counts the number of ways to add $1$ additional object to $k$ ordered objects (there are $k+1$ ways to do this), then perform the $A$-construction on the result (there are $a_{k+1}$ ways to do this). Using this one can give combinatorial proofs of the product rule and even the chain rule using combinatorial interpretations of taking products resp. compositions of generating functions; it's fun stuff. (I will try to hunt down references going into more detail later.)
When $A(x) = (1 + x)^n$ one way to combinatorially interpret its coefficients $a_k = {n \choose k}$ is that they are counting the number of ways to fill a row of $k$ boxes with distinct numbers from $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$ in increasing order; this is our combinatorial construction. Then the derivative
$$\begin{align*} \frac{d}{dx} A(x) &= \sum_{k \ge 1} k {n \choose k} x^{k-1} \\
 &= \sum_{k \ge 0} (k+1) {n \choose k+1} x^k \\
 &= n(1 + x)^{n-1} \\
 &= \sum_{k \ge 0} n {n-1 \choose k} x^k \end{align*}$$
counts the number of ways to add an additional box to $k$ boxes, then fill the result with distinct numbers from $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$ in increasing order. The above identity of generating functions is telling us that we can count the number of ways to do this in two ways:

Add the new box first, then fill; this gives $(k+1) {n \choose k+1}$ ways.
Decide what number goes into the new box first, then fill the rest; there are $n$ options for what goes in the new box, then ${n-1 \choose k}$ ways to fill in the rest of the boxes. Once this is done, the position of the new box is uniquely determined.

So this gives, so to speak, a combinatorial proof of a version of the power rule.
The $m^{th}$ derivative $\frac{d^m}{dx^m} A(x)$ then counts the number of ways to add $m$ new boxes, then perform the $A$-construction on the result. If $A(x)$ is a generating function this is always divisible by $m!$ because $m!$ is the number of orders in which we can add these new boxes. (Isn't that great?) Then the result $A^{(m)}(0)$ of plugging in $x = 0$ is counting the number of ways to add $m$ new boxes to an initially empty row of boxes, then performing the $A$-construction on the result; this is $m!$ times the number of ways to perform the $A$-construction on a row of $m$ boxes, which gives
$$\frac{A^{(m)}(0)}{m!} = a_m$$
as expected. This counting argument works for any generating function whatsoever.
On the other hand, if $A(x) = (1 + x)^n$, we have a second way to compute the $m^{th}$ derivative (after dividing by $m!$): generalizing the above argument, we can fill the $m$ new boxes first, which can be done in ${n \choose m}$ ways, then fill the remaining boxes, which can be done in ${n-m \choose k}$ ways. As above, the position of the new boxes is uniquely determined by order. Setting $k = 0$ gives
$$\frac{A^{(m)}(0)}{m!} = {n \choose m}$$
again as expected.

Unfortunately would you believe that I'm old enough that I no longer remember where I learned this stuff? There is a very brief discussion in Flajolet and Sedgewick's Analytic Combinatorics in I.6.2 (Flajolet and Sedgewick discuss "pointing" which involves an extra multiplication by $x$), and also on Wikipedia, which discusses differentiation in the context of combinatorial species (which is a way to make precise what exactly a "combinatorial construction" is). You need to be a bit careful when digging through the literature here because there is also a combinatorial interpretation of differentiation on exponential generating functions, which is closely related but a bit different.
In lieu of a reference let me briefly indicate how the combinatorial proof of the product rule goes. If $A(x) = \sum a_k x^k, B(x) = \sum b_k x^k$ are two generating functions describing two combinatorial constructions we can perform on $k$ ordered boxes, then their product
$$A(x) B(x) = \sum \left( \sum_{i+j=k} a_i b_j \right) x^k$$
counts the number of ways to split our $k$ ordered boxes into $i$ boxes on the left and $j$ boxes on the right, then perform the $A$-construction on the left boxes and the $B$-construction on the right boxes. So the derivative
$$\frac{d}{dx} A(x) B(x) = A'(x) B(x) + A(x) B'(x)$$
counts the number of ways to add a new box, then perform the above splitting + construction. The two terms of the product rule then correspond to whether the new box ends up in the boxes on the left or the boxes on the right!
We also get, for example, that $A(x)^n$ counts the number of ways to split up our $k$ boxes into $n$ segments, then perform the $A$-construction separately on each segment. So in the special case $\frac{d}{dx} A(x)^n = n A(x)^{n-1} A'(x)$ of the chain rule, the $n$ terms correspond to which of the $n$ segments the new box ends up in.

Thanks for this! :) It is VERY early morning where I live and I will need to give this a few re-reads but on first viewing it seems to make a great bit of sense. I have had some experience with generating functions but not loads so I'll do some brief research.

this is amazing! completely answers one of the problems that lived in my brain for years rent-free
